Tiller use on takeoff
When a commercial jet aircraft has been cleared for takeoff, does the PF use the tiller for steering, up to a certain speed? I've seen many vids where it seems the PF uses the yoke/sidestick for steering from the very beginning of the takeoff roll.

See also https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50877/when-does-an-airliner-switch-from-using-the-tiller-to-the-rudder

Usually, the nosewheel steering provided through the rudder pedals (not the yoke or sidestick) is sufficient. The tiller is useful for large deflections of the nosewheel, like turning from one taxiway to another that's 90 degrees off, but for small corrections like tracking the centerline, the less sensitivity & lower authority of the rudder pedals is preferable.
On takeoff roll, I typically guard the tiller until 80 knots, mainly in case of a sudden engine failure (or, worse, an engine seizure), which could try to yank the aircraft off the side of the runway pretty fast.  Above 80 knots, you have the authority of the rudder itself at work, and the tiller would be too sensitive even in the the engine seizure scenario. So above 80 knots you really don't want to be touching the tiller.
The case where you wouldn't have nosewheel steering thru the rudder pedals would be if the interconnect from the pedals to the NWS was deferred; I know it's in the MEL, but I've never seen it.  In that case, you'd need at least some pressure on the tiller to keep things tracking straight until there is enough airflow on the rudder that the pedals have adequate authority. And, in the case of an engine failure, you'd be going to the tiller right away anyhow -- and pulling the operating engine back to idle, and on the brakes (differentially, if needed), so there should be plenty of ways to maintain directional control in an engine-out scenario, even with that deferral.
In the C-130, there was no interconnect between the pedals and the NWS, so everything was the tiller, and sometimes differential power (or reverse) and differential braking (rarely). Instant response from the props made that a very viable way to taxi.  And that worked fine; the rudder became effective pretty quickly on takeoff roll -- having lots of airflow coming off the props probably helped out.
But the normal case in a 737 is, the pilots steer the nosewheel via the rudder pedals for the entire takeoff roll, and the tiller isn't used, only guarded.

I've tried no NSW in the CRJ sim using differential braking. Differential power to steer was less effective with the tail mounted engines. Sharp jabs of brake were necessary.  The B-29 had a free castering nosewheel and was reportedly a handful on the ground at the middling speeds below rudder effectiveness and was heavily dependent on differential outboard engine power.
